# Is it possible to write some data to the Internal Memory of Android 2.2 Tablet Device?

Tags: android

In my project I am trying to save many files in the memory such as Images , Videos and Audios. I have used `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. For the phone it works fine with the SD card support. But for the device like Tablet with android 2.2 version which has higher internal memory we actual can avoid using SD card. But I am not able to write the data to the internal memory. I have checked it in Samsung P6200 Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus without SD card. It saved inside `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/navya.android.sample/files/myDir/sampleVideo.mp3`

Is it possible to write some data to the Internal Memory of Android 2.2 Tablet Device?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to write some data to the Internal Memory of Android 2.2 Tablet Device?

It should be. The device might have some gross compatibility flaws.

> Any suggestions?

Read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: i need to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to write data. This is not actually working in Android 2.2 Tablet Device without SD card.

Comment: @NavyaRamesan: The only legitimate Android 2.2 tablet was the original Samsung Galaxy Tab, in which case you solve the problem by putting in an SD card, IIRC. Anything else did not pass the compatibility requirements -- for those, you would have to contact the manufacturer for advice.